# Spark Dataframe: Query counts of column having continuously the same result

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataset for warehouse stock where the current state is reported every two minutes.

I want to get the dates where there is no stock left i.e. `stock_amount = 0` and if the value remains at 0 for some time, get the count of each subsequent row where the stock_amount is 0. In other words, I want to get the dates where `stock_amount` *becomes* 0, and then the number of times where it remains 0.

For instance, given the below data

```
Row(date='24-06-2020 11:03:00', stock_amount = 1)
Row(date='24-06-2020 11:05:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='24-06-2020 11:07:00', stock_amount = 2)
Row(date='24-06-2020 11:09:00', stock_amount = 3)
Row(date='24-06-2020 16:32:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='24-06-2020 16:34:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='24-06-2020 16:36:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='24-06-2020 16:38:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='24-06-2020 16:40:00', stock_amount = 2)
```

The result should be:

```
  (date='24-06-2020 11:05:00', count=1)
  (date='24-06-2020 16:32:00', count=4)
```

And for this data,

```
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:03:00', stock_amount = 3)
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:05:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:07:00', stock_amount = 4)
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:09:00', stock_amount = 4)
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:11:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 12:13:00', stock_amount = 2)
Row(date='26-07-2020 17:32:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 17:34:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 17:36:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 17:38:00', stock_amount = 0)
Row(date='26-07-2020 17:40:00', stock_amount = 1)
```

the result should be:

```
   (date='26-07-2020 12:05:00', count=1)
   (date='26-07-2020 12:11:00', count=1)
   (date='26-07-2020 17:32:00',  count=4)
```

Comment: still needed some more clarity, on how it should be 2 times, since I can see 5 time it is 0. please add some more inputs for your scenario so that can assist you better

Comment: @smart_coder I added another example.

Comment: I can see 0->1 instances 2 times in the first time example and 3 times in the second example?? Or I may not have enough thinking to understand your usecase.

Comment: That is pretty much correct. Except the solution is to find when the stock_amount column becomes 0, not when it stops being 0.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with window function and some grouping.

*Note : The multiple steps are for more detailing, but can be combined in a single command.*

```
#%%
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
data= sqlContext.createDataFrame([
('24-06-2020 11:03:00',  1),
('24-06-2020 11:05:00',  0),
('24-06-2020 11:07:00',  2),
('24-06-2020 11:09:00',  3),
('24-06-2020 16:32:00',  0),
('24-06-2020 16:34:00',  0),
('24-06-2020 16:36:00',  0),
('24-06-2020 16:38:00',  0),
('24-06-2020 16:40:00',  2)],schema=['date','stock'])
data_grp = data.withColumn("stk_grp",(F.col('stock')!=0).cast('int'))
w= Window.orderBy('date')
data_sum = data_grp.withColumn("count_grp", F.sum('stk_grp').over(w))
data_stk = data_sum.withColumn("stk_zero",(F.col('stock')==0).cast('int'))
w1= Window.partitionBy('count_grp').orderBy('date')
data_res = data_stk.withColumn("fin_count", F.sum('stk_zero').over(w1))

#%%
data_filt = data_res.where("fin_count!=0")
data_res = data_filt.groupby('count_grp').agg(F.min('date').alias('date'),F.max('fin_count').alias('count'))

data_res.show()
+---------+-------------------+--------------+
|count_grp|               date|         count|
+---------+-------------------+--------------+
|        1|24-06-2020 11:05:00|             1|
|        3|24-06-2020 16:32:00|             4|
+---------+-------------------+--------------+
```